# Sub that compares 2 columns fast

Tags: performance, algorithm, vba, excel, comparative-review

This is an answer to this SO question: [Vba comparing 2 columns of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798996/vba-comparing-2-columns-of-data/49828639#49828639).

In that question the OP code is very slow (also not working properly but the problem is fixed)

I spent some time to implement a version with decent performance at 1M rows+

Note: I know `Activesheet` is discouraged (and I avoid it) but the Sub is quite generic (and it can be made even more so); the little utility can be convenient to users for quick checks - simply compare values on current sheet

---

Description

- Sets up 2 dictionaries (late-bound)
- Sets up the main UsedRange (ur) variable
- Deletes the results columns C and D
- Setups 4 arrays

  - `arrA` for the **first column to be compared** (Col A)
  - `arrB` for the **second column to be compared** (Col B)
  - `arrC` for the 1st **result column C** (from Col A, which shows vals not found in col B)
  - `arrD` for the 2nd **result column D** (from Col B, showing vals not found in col A)

    - (Each column can be a constant, or Optional Param with default vals)
- Load data to dictionaries:

  - `For` loop 1: adds all elements in Col A as keys, in dictionary dColA
  - `For` loop 2: adds all elements in Col B as keys, in dictionary dColB
- Compare dictionary items

  - `For` loop 3: for each itm in dColA checks their existence in dColB

    - If an item is not found, it places it in the 3th array (arrC)
  - `For` loop 4: for each itm in dColB checks their existence in dColA

    - If an item is not found, it places it in the 4th array (arrD)
- At the end, it places both `arr3` and `arr4` back on the range (Col C and D respectively)

---

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Compare2Cols()
    Dim dColA As Object:    Set dColA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim dColB As Object:    Set dColB = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim ur As Range:        Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ur.Columns("C:D").Delete
    Dim arrA As Variant:    arrA = ur.Columns("A")
    Dim arrB As Variant:    arrB = ur.Columns("B")
    Dim arrC As Variant:    arrC = ur.Columns("C")
    Dim arrD As Variant:    arrD = ur.Columns("D")

    Dim itm As Variant

    For Each itm In arrA
        dColA(itm) = 0
    Next
    For Each itm In arrB
        dColB(itm) = 0
    Next
    Dim r As Long
    For Each itm In dColA
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColB.Exists(itm) Then arrC(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 1 in 2
    Next
    r = 0
    For Each itm In dColB
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColA.Exists(itm) Then arrD(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 2 in 1
    Next
    ur.Columns("C") = arrC
    ur.Columns("D") = arrD
End Sub
```

---

Test results - dictionaries:

```
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows:    10,001; Time:   0.047 sec
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows:    20,001; Time:   0.109 sec
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows:    30,001; Time:   0.156 sec
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows:    40,001; Time:   0.234 sec
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows:    50,001; Time:   0.296 sec
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows:   100,001; Time:   1.232 sec
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows:   500,001; Time:  31.934 sec
Compare2ColsUsingDictionaries() - Rows: 1,048,576; Time: 126.797 sec
```

Test results - collections ([suggested by @juvian](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192166/sub-that-compares-2-columns-fast/192238#192238), about 4 times faster for large data)

```
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows:    10,001; Time:   0.262 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows:    20,001; Time:   0.539 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows:    30,001; Time:   0.813 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows:    40,001; Time:   1.109 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows:    50,001; Time:   1.410 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows:   100,001; Time:   2.945 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows:   500,001; Time:  15.730 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()  - Rows: 1,048,576; Time:  33.719 sec
```

---

Image of test results

[image: TestData]

---

.

Other versions (combinations of reduced `For` loops) I've already tried:

.

**V2** (combined For 1 and 2) -  significant increase in execution time from 2 min to 3

---

```vb
Public Sub Compare2ColsV2()
    Dim dColA As Object:    Set dColA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim dColB As Object:    Set dColB = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim ur As Range:        Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ur.Columns("C:D").Delete

    Dim arrA As Variant:    arrA = ur.Columns("A")
    Dim arrB As Variant:    arrB = ur.Columns("B")
    Dim arrC As Variant:    arrC = ur.Columns("C")
    Dim arrD As Variant:    arrD = ur.Columns("D")

    Dim itm As Variant, r As Long

    For r = 1 To UBound(arrA)   'based on UsedRange (same LastRow)
        dColA(arrA(r, 1)) = 0
        dColB(arrB(r, 1)) = 0
    Next

    r = 0
    For Each itm In dColA
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColB.Exists(itm) Then arrC(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 1 in 2
    Next

    r = 0
    For Each itm In dColB
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColA.Exists(itm) Then arrD(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 2 in 1
    Next

    ur.Columns("C") = arrC
    ur.Columns("D") = arrD
End Sub
```

---

.

**V3** (combined For 2 and 4) - No improvement (slower by about 3 secs);

---

```vb
Public Sub Compare2ColsV3()
    Dim dColA As Object:    Set dColA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim dColB As Object:    Set dColB = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim ur As Range:        Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ur.Columns("C:D").Delete

    Dim arrA As Variant:    arrA = ur.Columns("A")
    Dim arrB As Variant:    arrB = ur.Columns("B")
    Dim arrC As Variant:    arrC = ur.Columns("C")
    Dim arrD As Variant:    arrD = ur.Columns("D")

    Dim itm As Variant, r As Long

    For Each itm In arrA
        dColA(itm) = 0
    Next
    For Each itm In arrB
        dColB(itm) = 0
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColA.Exists(itm) Then arrD(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 2 in 1
    Next
    r = 0
    For Each itm In dColA
        r = r + 1
        If Not dColB.Exists(itm) Then arrC(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 1 in 2
    Next

    ur.Columns("C") = arrC
    ur.Columns("D") = arrD
End Sub
```

---

Any performance improvements or suggestions are appreciated

**PS.** I also tested 2 types of loops over variant arrays, using `For r = 1 To UBound(arrA)` vs. `For Each itm In arrA` with no other changes - there is no noticeable difference in speed between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s worth a shot trying with Collections instead of Dictionary. Sounds counter intuitive but have read in several places that for big data it is in fact faster.

One of them is : [Count distinct or unique values](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/count-distinct-or-unique-values-vba-udf/)

It is true that collections don´t have an exists method, but you can take advantage that it throws an error if you try to access with a key that does not exist and make your own method: [Check if key exists in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291597/how-to-check-the-key-is-exists-in-collection-or-not/42293106#42293106)

Another place worth checking is [Get unique values from array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33481391/3308055)

Implementation (pb)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Compare2ColsUsingCollections()
    Dim t As Double, tr As String:  t = Timer
    Dim dColA As Collection:    Set dColA = New Collection
    Dim dColB As Collection:    Set dColB = New Collection
    Dim ur As Range:            Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ur.Columns("C:D").Delete
    Dim arrA As Variant:        arrA = ur.Columns("A")
    Dim arrB As Variant:        arrB = ur.Columns("B")
    Dim arrC As Variant:        arrC = ur.Columns("C")
    Dim arrD As Variant:        arrD = ur.Columns("D")

    Dim itm As Variant, r As Long, s As String
    For Each itm In arrA
        s = CStr(itm)
        If IsMissing(dColA, s) Then dColA.Add s, s
    Next
    For Each itm In arrB
        s = CStr(itm)
        If IsMissing(dColB, s) Then dColB.Add s, s
    Next
    For Each itm In dColA
        r = r + 1
        If IsMissing(dColB, itm) Then arrC(r, 1) = itm  'Find Col 1 in 2
    Next
    r = 0
    For Each itm In dColB
        r = r + 1
        If IsMissing(dColA, itm) Then arrD(r, 1) = itm  'Find Col 1 in 2
    Next
    ur.Columns("C") = arrC: ur.Columns("D") = arrD
    tr = "Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows: " & Format(ur.Rows.Count, "#,###") & "; "
    Debug.Print tr & "Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function IsMissing(ByRef c As Collection, ByVal fld As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo IsMissingError
    Dim v As Variant
    v = c(fld)
    Exit Function
IsMissingError:
    IsMissing = True
End Function
```

---

Test results

```
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows: 1,048,576; Time: 33.770 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows:   500,001; Time: 15.730 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows:   100,001; Time:  2.945 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows:    50,001; Time:  1.410 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows:    40,001; Time:  1.109 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows:    30,001; Time:  0.813 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows:    20,001; Time:  0.539 sec
Compare2ColsUsingCollections() - Rows:    10,001; Time:  0.262 sec
```

---

Same results with same data:

Dictionaries

[image: Dictionaries]

Collections

[image: Collections]

Comment: Thanks juvian, this actually addresses the main performance issue - it's 4 times faster than dictionaries, for large data!

Comment: @paulbica do you plan to make it generic or only for integers?

Comment: Generic, but if you have any other suggestions for improving it specifically for Longs, you can add them to your answer as well (doesn't hurt)

Comment: Great! I'll leave the question open for a few days, in case someone else can improve the performance (unlikely), so I'll probably accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @paul Integers - [integers are obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`.

Comment: Thanks @Raystafarian (this is why I mentioned `Longs` in my previous comment)

Answer (score 6):

I'll be up-front, I **detest** colons in VBA. I just do. I feel like it doesn't make it any more clear and it seems more cluttered, especially to those who aren't familiar with them. So, that's my statement for that, and I won't include it in the review.

---

#### Confusion

That being said, why are you using entire columns? Because you've already defined the last row based on the `UsedRange`? It's a bit misleading, but that's okay. Maybe rename `ur` to be more clear. `UserRange` for instance. And why create variants of columns you just deleted?

> ```
> ur.Columns("C:D").Delete
> Dim arrC As Variant:    arrC = ur.Columns("C")
> Dim arrD As Variant:    arrD = ur.Columns("D")
> ```

If you need some empty variants sized, you can do that explicitly using the `UBound` of one of the other arrays. I know it seems excessive, but someone may expect there to be data in a variant that was set to a range, right?

And I know you were going for flexible, but `arrA arrB arrC arrD` aren't doing me any favors. What are they? Is `arrC` a result of `arrA`? If there's a relationship, maybe make that clear. I know it's rough trying to stay generic and flexible, but I couldn't *not* say anything.

Also, what if my `UsedRange` doesn't match your expectation? What if it's more than 4 columns, or less that 4 columns? What if it's in `D:G` - the `A` to `D` will look strange to me.

---

#### Dictionaries

Nice work with the dictionaries. I love using them for removing duplicates and I think you did a good job. However, maybe rename `itm` to `key` to be more clear. I also enjoy the late binding much more than early binding, but that's my *opinion*.

---

#### Populating

When you populate your arrays here

> ```
> For Each itm In dColA
>     r = r + 1
>     If Not dColB.Exists(itm) Then arrC(r, 1) = itm   'Find Col 1 in 2
> Next
> ```

You're increasing the row and leaving it blank if the `if` condition isn't met. Is that on purpose, to leave blanks? But what happens with the count of the dictionary is less than the bounds of the array? Do you need to shift up or leave blanks? It's not explicitly stated what the goal is there, in the code. I think your best bet would to create a function with a name as to what it does, pass your dictionary to it and return the new variant. Your name of the function *should* be able to tell us a lot.

---

Overall, I think this is a pretty solid procedure, but it could use some refactoring and a little bit more clarity and *maybe* some error handling.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick response! To answer your point: Colons are a personal preference (I know they're not favored) but I use them extremely carefully for visual alignment - to me I `Dim` and I `Set1` - done (I know where to look fast). 2. _why are you using entire columns?_ - Where am I using entire columns (I'm using the entire columns of the `UsedRange`). 3. _And why create variants of columns you just deleted_ those are the results columns - they need to be empty before every run. 4. `arrA`, `arrB`, `arrC`, `arrD` as parameters would become `vArrColToCompare1`, `vArrColToCompare2`, etc

Comment: The `UsedRange` is debatable: what if the user has empty cells `.End(xlDown)` will eliminate the rest of the cells bellow. This utility is not fully generic yet - I just wanted to see if I can optimize it first. Lastly: _You're increasing the row and leaving it blank if the if condition isn't met_ - that's my intent - I meant to show the position where the value was not found in the other column; _But what happens with the count of the dictionary is less than the bounds of the array?_ good point - I need to fix this... (I was moving between dictionaries and arrays quite a bit)

Comment: Can you think of any performance improvements at all?

Comment: I just meant if you're starting with `usedrange` then you know the `last row`. And it *looks* like you're using entire columns, I know you aren't. The only thing I might do differently is use one variant instead of 4, but I'm not sure that would be much of an improvement. Maybe there's a better algorithm, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for fast performance and you are only dealing with countable numbers (e.g. Longs), this approach would be considerably faster. My code below assumes you'd only be working with `Longs`.

Basically, the way this works is enumerating all possible numbers you expect to see, then flips them to true when it's been seen. I do this over each range, then dump the results to `Long` arrays.

This really only works if you know what the min/max range you'd be working in, so it has limited usefulness, however it might be a good fit for your specific use case.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Compare2NumColsUsingBoolArrays()
    Dim t As Double, tr As String:      t = Timer
    Dim appFuncs As WorksheetFunction:  Set appFuncs = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim ur As Range: Set ur = ActiveSheet.UsedRange:    ur.Columns("C:D").Delete
    Set ur = ur.Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 1):              Set ur = ur.Offset(1)

    Dim arr As Variant:     arr = ur.Columns("A:D")
    Dim lbA As Long:        lbA = appFuncs.Min(ur.Columns("A"))
    Dim ubA As Long:        ubA = appFuncs.Max(ur.Columns("A"))
    Dim lbB As Long:        lbB = appFuncs.Min(ur.Columns("B"))
    Dim ubB As Long:        ubB = appFuncs.Max(ur.Columns("B"))
    Dim minN As Long:       minN = IIf(lbA < lbB, lbA, lbB)
    Dim maxN As Long:       maxN = IIf(ubA > ubB, ubA, ubB)
    Dim nArrA() As Boolean: ReDim nArrA(minN To maxN)
    Dim nArrB() As Boolean: ReDim nArrB(minN To maxN)

    Dim r As Long, rC As Long, rD As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)                    'Arr index = value (true/false)
        nArrA(arr(r, 1)) = True
        nArrB(arr(r, 2)) = True
    Next

    For r = minN To maxN
        If nArrA(r) And Not nArrB(r) Then       'In ColA, not in ColB
            rC = rC + 1:    arr(rC, 3) = r
        ElseIf Not nArrA(r) And nArrB(r) Then   'In ColB, not in ColA
            rD = rD + 1:    arr(rD, 4) = r
        End If
    Next
    ur.Columns("A:D") = arr
    tr = "Compare2NumColsUsingBoolArrays() - Rows:" & Format(ur.Rows.Count, "#,###") & ";"
    Debug.Print tr & "Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

.

Test results

```
Compare2ColsUsingCollections()   - Rows: 1,048,575; Time: 32.563 sec
Compare2NumColsUsingBoolArrays() - Rows: 1,048,575; Time:  3.139 sec
```

---

[image: Test results]

---

.

Notes:

- Adapted code to exclude Headers, and place results back in Col C and D
- Test results don't show the positioning of missing elements

Comment: At first I was a bit skeptic, but for strictly comparing Longs, this is an interesting approach, and also very fast - 3 seconds! You have my vote. I edited your answer to determine the lower and upper bounds of the boolean arrays dynamically (it accepts negatives as well), and place the results back on the Range. I also tested it with the same data set and included the result measurement

Comment: Hopefully it helps!